# \'. gives error when fontspec package is used

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec

The following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
The logo `\TeX\'.
\end{document}
```

produces the error:

```
./test.tex:5: Argument of \end has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.5 \end
        {document}
?
```

What's wrong here?

Just to avoid ***why would you want to put an acute accent over a peroid*** kind of argument, I need to say that for a TeX course that I am teaching, I use The TeXBook and this particular example comes from the TeXBook in chapter 3.

Comment: Hi and welcome. `\'` is not a valid control sequence there.

Comment: @Johannes_B Why?

Comment: @ChrisS Because there is a difference between (plain)TeX and LaTeX. Try `\TeX\'.
\vfill\eject\bye` and compile it using `pdftex` (not `pdflatex`).

Comment: @Johannes_B: I do not think so, remove `fontspec` and run `pdflatex` and see the result yourself.

Comment: Ok, works with pdflatex as well; my mistake. Then i think `fontspec` has some kind of failsafe, as it won't put together characters but uses the unicode ones provided by the font.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi Could you try to come up with a more descriptive title for this question? Something that gives other users a better idea of what this question is about *without* having to read it. Also, I’m not sure if your name is very common or if you’ve created a bunch of duplicate accounts (see [this search](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=vafa%20khalighi)), but if the latter is the case, you can request [having your accounts merged](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `\'` becomes `\EU1-cmd\' \EU1\'` and then `\EU1-cmd` checks if the combination

```
\\EU1\'-.
```

is defined; the control sequence has `\EU1\'-.` as name and can be checked by

```
\expandafter\show\csname\string\EU1\string\'-.\endcsname
```

which gives

```
> \\EU1\'-.=macro:
->\TIPAaccent {\textdotacute }.
```

Now the problem follows, because `\TIPAaccent` wants two arguments, and it finds `\end` which is surely not a good token for it.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Gentium}
\begin{document}
\'.e
\end{document}
```

Gentium is needed because Latin Modern doesn't have the required glyph.

[image]

In conclusion, `\TeX\'.` shows a bad usage of the backslash after `\TeX`.

If you need `\'.` for demonstration purposes, you can undeclare the composite using the command I suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58115/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\providecommand*\UndeclareTextComposite[3]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname\expandafter\string\csname
  #2\endcsname\string#1-#3\endcsname\relax}

\UndeclareTextComposite{\'}{EU1}{.}

\begin{document}
`\TeX\'.
\end{document}
```

The placement of the accent isn't the same as with `cmr10`; this depends on the fonts.

[image]

Comment: I know you would come along. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: Yes, it does but it also shows a `fontspec` bug.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi Why should it be a bug? The fact that it loads TIPA macros is documented and the construction `\'.{<char>}`  is in the manual of TIPA. Surprising feature, maybe.

Comment: @egreg: Because it is not consistent with what the TeXBook in chapter 3 describes. Knuth says there that `\'` puts an acute accent over the next nonblank character.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi The TeXbook doesn't talk about LaTeX. Would you say that different behavior of `\line` in LaTeX from what is described in the TeXbook is a LaTeX bug?

Comment: @egreg: No, I would not say that for `\line` but at least `\'` behaves the same (provided you do not load `fontspec`).

Comment: @VafaKhalighi No, `\.` works quite differently in LaTeX than in Plain; the effect is similar, but not necessarily in all occasions.

Comment: @egreg: That is too bad. It is very painful when you have to make some lecture notes about TeX in LaTeX. Anyway, thanks for your clarifications.

Comment: @vafa I added a workaround for undeclaring the composite character.