# '\v{C}' character not rendered in fonts which don't have 'Č' with T1 encoding

Tags: font-encodings

I'm trying to typeset a word that contains a 'Č', and due to context, it has to appear in a sans, bold, quattrocento font.

However, whenever I have the fontencoding set to T1, then the character doesn't appear at all. The following MWE creates a blank page but should create a single bold sans 'Č'.

Commenting out the fontenc line seems to fix the problem, but I'd prefer to have a special case for this character then change the fontencoding for the entire document

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[sf,scaled=0.9]{quattrocento}

\begin{document}
\textbf{\textsf{\v{C}}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The font misses several precomposed accented glyphs. At the expense of the possibility to hyphenate the words containing Č, you can do

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sf,scaled=0.9]{quattrocento}

\providecommand*\UndeclareTextComposite[3]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname\expandafter\string\csname
  #2\endcsname\string#1-#3\endcsname\relax}

\UndeclareTextComposite{\v}{T1}{C}

\begin{document}

\textsf{\v{C}}
\textbf{\textsf{\v{C}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58115/4427 for `\UndeclareTextCompositeCommand`. Do similarly for other missing accented characters you need.

It's immaterial whether you use `\v{C}` or directly `Č`.

**Note.** The maintainer of the LaTeX font package remarked that the glyphs are missing because they're not even in the OpenType font the TeX version is derived from.

Comment: Is there an easy solution to provide accents for those letters: `ąęłżĄĘŁŻ`? I managed to use the same solution, which you described for obtaining `ńśćźóŃŚĆŹÓ`, but I failed to retrieve the latter ones.

Comment: @andywiecko I'm afraid that the ogonek is very difficult to place correctly.

Comment: @andywiecko Use a different font.

Comment: what about replacing ogonek with cedilla? I know that this is ugly solution, but is it doable?

Comment: @andywiecko I'd not do it even under threat.

Comment: Yeah, crazy idea with cedilla :-) any suggestion for font replacement? IMHO quattrocento sans nicely supports roman ebgaramond

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using the OpenType font.  The version of Quattrocento Sans I downloaded does not contain the Unicode characters U+030C (combining caron) or U+010C (Latin Capital Letter C with Caron), but you can fake it with U+02C7 (Caron) and `\accent`.  You can also use [Ulrike Fischer’s solution to this similar problem.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476566/caron-accent-va-doesnt-render-without-usepackagexecjk)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, newunicodechar}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Quattrocento Roman}[Scale = 1.0]
\setsansfont{Quattrocento Sans}

\renewcommand\v[1]{{\accent"02C7 #1}}
\newunicodechar{Č}{\v{C}}
\newunicodechar{č}{\v{c}}

\begin{document}
\textbf{\textsf{\v{C}Č}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Quattrocento Sans font sample]

Warning: this supports Č (U+010C), but won’t necessarily work if you write it as Č (U+43 U+030C).