# Cedilla failing with XeLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, xetex, accents

This MWE works correctly with pdflatex but fails to produce an o-cedilla (o̧) with xelatex even if you uncomment the fontspec.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Here is a c-cedilla: \c{c} and an o-cedilla: \c{o}
\end{document}
```

I'm missing something, but what?

Comment: `Missing character: There is no ̧ (U+0327) in font [lmroman10regular]:mapping=tex-text;!`

Comment: xelatex defaults to using the Unicode combining accent, but latin modern is rather short on diacritics

Answer (score 5):

This is a problem with the font, compounded by a bad design decision forty years ago.

By default, when the document tries to use a character that the current font does not have, TeX replaces it with a blank space.  You’re supposed to carefully proofread every line and catch this.

If you add the command `\tracinglostchars=3`, this will become an error, and the TeX engine will crash with the message:

> ! Missing character: There is no ̧ (U+0327) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping
> =tex-text;.

I suggest you add `\tracinglostchars=3` to all your documents.  (I see that the default behavior is now to at least print a warning message to the console instead of failing silently, which used to require a different command.)

That tells us what the problem is: the default font that `fontspec` loads doesn’t have a combining cedilla accent.  To fix this, load a font that does, such as New Computer Modern.  The `fontsetup` package is the easiest way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}

\begin{document}
Here is a c-cedilla: \c{c} and an o-cedilla: \c{o}
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern sample]

There is no precomposed o̧ in Unicode, although there is a ǫ (U+01EB), and Latin Modern has it.  There is a good chance that you really want an ogonek, not a cedilla.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\DeclareRobustCommand\oogonek{\symbol{"01EB}}

\begin{document}
Here is a c-cedilla: \c{c} and an o-ogonek: \oogonek
\end{document}
```

This was meant more as an example, but: David Carlisle points out that `\k{o}` works for ǫ.  So would entering the precomposed UTF-8 character into your source file directly.

Comment: `\k{o}` works for U+01EB with no definitions required

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. On modern OSes, you’d probably want to type in the UTF-8 character using whatever method you normally use for your native language.

Comment: well yes but given my native language typing `\k o` likely quicker than working out how the heck to type an ogonek on  a UK keyboard:-)

Comment: No, I was specifically looking for the o-cedilla as an example to a user.

Answer (score 2):

You coud make a cedilla, but `\textcommabelow` is available out of the box, and may (or may not) be suitable

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{TU}{o}{\textcommabelow{o}}
\begin{document}
Here is a c-cedilla: \c{c} and an o-cedilla: \c{o}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Undeclare the text composite and redeclare it; however it's likely that you want “o with ogonek” rather than with a cedilla.

The problem is that Latin Modern has no “combining cedilla” character U+0327.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58115/4427
\providecommand*\UndeclareTextComposite[3]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname\expandafter\string\csname
  #2\endcsname\string#1-#3\endcsname\relax}

\UndeclareTextComposite{\c}{TU}{o}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\c}{TU}{o}{\accent"B8 o}

\begin{document}

Here is a c-cedilla: \c{c} and an o-cedilla: \c{o}

Probably you want \k{o} (o with ogonek)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are some languages with an o-cedilla, though.

Comment: There definitely are. For example, Marshallese modern orthography uses o̧ to denote an open back rounded vowel. In fact, Adobe-Latin-5 character set requires supporting the combination of o with cedilla.

Comment: This was why I wanted an o-cedilla (Marshallese) as an example to a user. Embarrassing when pdflatex does it and xelatex doesn't, when you're trying to extol the Unicode capabilities of the latter over the former :-)

Comment: @PeterFlynn Complain with the developers of Latin Modern or use a different font.